# mysql equivalent expression to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there any shorter expression exists, than this:

```
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'


SELECT id FROM orders WHERE posted='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I mean something like:

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE posted=null ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I hope this is the schema you wanted to see:

```
array(19) {
  ["TABLE_CATALOG"]=>
  NULL
  ["TABLE_SCHEMA"]=>
  string(13) "teleprintfejl"
  ["TABLE_NAME"]=>
  string(13) "megrendelesek"
  ["COLUMN_NAME"]=>
  string(7) "posted"
  ["ORDINAL_POSITION"]=>
  string(2) "20"
  ["COLUMN_DEFAULT"]=>
  NULL
  ["IS_NULLABLE"]=>
  string(2) "NO"
  ["DATA_TYPE"]=>
  string(8) "datetime"
  ["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"]=>
  NULL
  ["CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH"]=>
  NULL
  ["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]=>
  NULL
  ["NUMERIC_SCALE"]=>
  NULL
  ["CHARACTER_SET_NAME"]=>
  NULL
  ["COLLATION_NAME"]=>
  NULL
  ["COLUMN_TYPE"]=>
  string(8) "datetime"
  ["COLUMN_KEY"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["EXTRA"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["PRIVILEGES"]=>
  string(31) "select,insert,update,references"
  ["COLUMN_COMMENT"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Please post the schema for that table.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting something more like the output of 'Show create table `order`', but the essential thing here is that your `posted` column is typed as DATETIME NOT NULL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that `posted` is a `DATETIME`. You can use `0`.

```
posted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

is the same as

```
posted = 0
```

Comment: plus one . I used with TIMESTAMP. the same :)

Answer (score 0):

that's up to your structure, when you create it, you can use null as default and when you make a select you will use:

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE posted IS null ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT:**

```
mysql> create table tiempo (fecha datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into tiempo values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tiempo;
+-------+
| fecha |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into tiempo values ('2000-02-02 02:02:02');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tiempo;
+---------------------+
| fecha               |
+---------------------+
| NULL                |
| 2000-02-02 02:02:02 |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tiempo where fecha is not null;
+---------------------+
| fecha               |
+---------------------+
| 2000-02-02 02:02:02 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I can't set default for datetime type, is it possible?

Comment: I have tested this and works (I still dont know why `posted IS null` works and `posted=null` dont)

Comment: Beacuse `NULL` is not a blue and you can't compare it with anything. It's not equal to any other value. It's not equal to another `NULL` either! `NULL = NULL` results in neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. It results in `UNKNOWN` (SQL uses a 3-valued logic).

Comment: @ypercube very interesting logic. My question would be what is the difference between `NULL` and `NULL` if they are not equal?

Comment: They are not equal, they are the same. `NULL IS NULL` results in `TRUE`. But `NULL = NULL` is `UNKNOWN` because (think of NULL as a placeholder for an unknown (yet) value, you don't what values there may be placed there. So, you don't really know (yet) and you may never do if these two will be equal or unequal.)

Comment: And of course above I did **not** mean that *"Beacuse `NULL` is not a blue"*. But : *"Because NULL is not a **value**"*

Comment: He's looking for 0 values. NULL values are quite different from 0.

Comment: as ypercube said, null is NOTHING, just null, try to make some math operation over NULL and everything will be null

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(id) as id FROM orders WHERE posted=0;
```

Comment: +1 for using `max()` instead of `order by` (but it is not the same.)

Comment: it is same as `SELECT id FROM orders WHERE posted='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: but i have to use: `$row['max(id)']` instead of `$row['id']` after fetching it associative.